# Google Apps Sync is not enabled for your email account

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I am trying to set up **Google Apps Sync** on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine.  The only thing I really want it for is to sync my calendar from Outlook to Google so that if someone sends me a meeting request on Outlook I don't have to re-enter it manually into Google Calendar.

When install it, it asks for my Google user and password details, then works for a while. Then I get this:

> ---------------------------
>   Error signing in
>   ---------------------------
>   Google Apps Sync is not enabled for your email account.
>   Please ask your domain administrator to enable it.

What "email account" is it talking about? Gmail? Outlook? And what exactly is involved in "enabling" it?

Comment: try this: http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Google Apps **for Business** (i.e. you pay for it) then you should be able to use this, in which case I'd contact your domain admin to see if this is enabled for your account.

If you have the **free edition** of Google Apps, then this is unavailable to you unless you upgrade to the Business version.

All that is detailed on the [Google Apps Outlook Sync page](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/outlook_sync.html).

That said, it sounds like all you need is [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955), which works with any Google Calendar login (Apps or otherwise). I used this for a long time, until I got a phone that would sync with both Google and Exchange.